# How to provide Static method in Forms?

Tags: c#, forms, static

I just changed my Modifier menu into public and now I'm getting this

"CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HomeForm.checkBeamToolStripMenuItem"

How do I provide static method in my coding? thanks in advance

My Code was :

```
private void AnalysisForm_FormClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    HomeForm.checkBeamToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
 }
```

Comment: are HomeForm and AnalysisForm defined in seperate projects? if yes, you need to pass the instance of the called form (HomeForm for example) to calling form (AnalysisForm) during its initialization.

Comment: If HomeForm opened AnalysisForm, then simply wire up and the FormClosed() event of AnalysisForm, **in HomeForm when you created AnalysisForm**, and you won't need to pass any references at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a classic mistake that seems to cause a ton of similar questions here on StackOverflow which is how to reference one form from another.  (search for that here on stackoverflow and you will find a lot of variations on how to do that )

But the basic idea to do that is you need an object reference to the other form.   What you are trying to do is access the class "HomeForm" which isn't an object.

so somewhere your forms are created, what you need to do is pass the object reference to the analysis form so you can tell it to do things.

```
var homeform = new HomeForm();
var analysis = new AnalysisForm(homeform);
```

though, I'd do it quite different for myself, start with making a method on homeform instead of accessing it's controls.